# Why the search for Childish Gambino?

Tags: plot-explanation, yesterday

In [*Yesterday* (2019)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yesterday_(2019_film)), Jack Malik is searching for some iconic performers when trying to understand what is going on after his accident.

One of his searches is for `Childish Gambino` (= [Donald Glover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Glover)). Is there a particular reason for this search (a hidden joke, friendship between Himesh Patel and him, ...) or is it just that apparently Jack is a fan?

Comment: I would say he search for Childish Gambino because he's a musician. Donald Glover is an actor. The latter can exist and work in "new world" but Gambino might never be made up and created music.

Answer (score -1):

Childish Gambino is a mixed range of sounds and styles so maybe he isn't into pigeon holes. Plus the younger generation today like him .. I like his music ..

It's like typing Billie Eilish into Google trying to pull the young crowd in with that reference.

Comment: Your answer is more of an opinion on Childlish Gambino rather than an answer about the movie...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/85189)

Comment: @TK-421 It very much tries to give reasons for why it might have been included in the film, the answerer's personal opinion notwithstanding. It could provide more backing for the general trend it's positing, but it's very much trying to answer the question asked.